# OpenVZ Container Restart

Tags: openvz, containers

I'm wondering if there are any public scripts to automatically restart OpenVZ containers on certain load amount / high cpu. Trying to limit my containers on my personal machine, thanks.

Comment: this is hammer approach, if you wan't to script it really you can see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen on : http://openvz.org/Loadavg ; load average of some container can be acquired with

> vzctl exec $CTID cat /proc/loadavg

you can script this easily with something like

```
#!/bin/bash

# loop over all OpenVZ containers
for container in $(vzlist -o ctid | egrep -o '[0-9]+')
do
  if (( $(bc <<< "$(vzctl exec $container cat /proc/loadavg | cut -d' ' -f1) <= 0.2") == 1 ))
  then
        echo "Load is less than 0.2"
  else
        echo "Load is above 0.2, stopping container $container"
        vzctl stop $container 

  fi
done
```

It uses the fact that load averages of respective intervals 1 5 and 15 can be read from /proc/loadavg

Comment: Thank you. I'm unfamiliar with bash scripting. How would I make it kill the process?

Comment: if this script is ran inside OpenVZ container as I understood from your question, you adjust load which is too high and restart with 'reboot' command; just add it below echo command in the script.

Comment: I want to run it on the host node to check for containers load. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: I've updated answer with more specific approach to run on system which hosts OpenVZ containers

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I'll give this a try. Would the best way to keep it running is with a cronjob?

Comment: sure you can add it to run as cronjob every few min; also please don't forget to upvote/accept answer if you found it helpful :))

Comment: Will do, thank you. Would it possible to do with process percentages and stop them?

Comment: what kind of percentage? please expand your question or add new comment with details and I'll do my best to help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18541/discussion-between-user44754-and-hrvoje-spoljar).

Comment: I opened up a chat.

Comment: Yea, I was there but nobody responded...